# set a variable equal to a value, not a reference

Tags: javascript

When I initialize an object I want to set `this.sound` to the current value of `Dog.sound`.

The code below appears to make `this.sound` a reference to `Dog.sound`'s value. How can I grab the value instead of a reference?

```
init: function() {
  this.sound = Dog.sound;
}
```

Comment: But I'm only using a single attribute of that object

Comment: If the value is a "primitive" type (string,number,boolean...) then it's not a reference. If it's an object (object,array,..) then you have to clone it. There are many questions in SO on how to clone arrays and objects.

Comment: @elclanrs - feel free to use as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is a "primitive" type (string, number, boolean...) then it's not a reference. If it's an object (object, array...) then you have to clone it. There are many questions in SO on how to clone arrays and objects:

- [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)
- [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: It just depends on what is meant by "clone" and what is meant by "copy". ;-)